# How does `Nullable<T> t = null` work?

Tags: c#, nullable, roslyn

Since I was wondering about the efficiency of certain operations on `Nullable<T>`, I went to check the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e) on the Microsoft site (and learned that `HasValue` and `GetValueOrDefault` don't involve any switching whereas `.Value` does). Looking through the file, I noticed that it is an immutable type with an implicit conversion from `T`,

```
 public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
     return new Nullable<T>(value);
 }
```

which I suppose allows me to write a line like

```
int? x; 
x = 3;
```

However, this does not explain how

```
x = null;
```

works. `Nullable` is a value type, so in general, this is not allowed. Initially I expected an overload of `operator=` or something similar, but I could not figure out what the argument of that should be (apart from a `Nullable<T>`).

I guess then that the compiler knows about `Nullable`s and treats them in a special way, but I would guess that the development team would have wanted to keep this to a minimum so I am wondering what exactly the compiler knows. How does it handle a line like `x = null` and what other things that I could not find in the [reference implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e) does it do behind the scenes?

---

Comment: `null` in this case interpreted as `default(Nullable<T>)`.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl, but this only works for `Nullable<T>`. I am not allowed to write `S s = null` for any other value type `S`. So I was wondering on what level this is handled for nullables, possibly with a link to (e.g. Roslyn) source.

Comment: @DStanley is it the CLR that interprets this, or the compiler? Because I assume that `default(Nullable<T>) == new T()`, i.e. assigning `null` has the same effect as calling the default constructor explicitly.

Comment: @CompuChip [The compiler](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>il/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3azIyAPwwqMALwwIwIkRyyAvtj1AAAA==).

Comment: @CompuChip Not sure what you want to know. According to C# specification **6.1.5 Null literal conversions: An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable type.** There is no such conversion from null literal to not nullable value type, so that you are not allowed to write `S s = null`.

Comment: @DStanley could you point me to the duplicate please?

Comment: @CompuChip The link should be above the question now.

Comment: @DStanley No, the CLR has nothing special going on here.  It's the compiler binding an implicit conversion operator to the assignment.  Having the CLR doing anything would imply that the binding wasn't done until runtime, which isn't the case.

Comment: @DStanley thanks, that answer covers everything I'm looking for :)